# WinSock как на сервере узнать, что клиент отключился

Tags: c++, winsock

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Есть ли у winsock какой-то способ узнать, что от сокета отключились, или это необходимо писать самому?

Comment: Который раз уже замечаю, что на вполне нормальный вопрос находится какой-то контрацептив, который бездумно минусует и ставит вопрос на закрытие. Гюльчитай, открой личико, напиши коммент!

Comment: а он никогда не признается. У меня куча ответов, где просто кто то минусует без каких то объяснений. Думаю, что когда то видимо "не так ответил" и на меня "обиделись". И теперь мне минусуют. И тут видимо тоже самое - не смог человек осилить сокеты - теперь минусует вопросы с сокетами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть только один надежный способ - послать что то и дождаться ответа. Эту команду можно внести прямо в команды протокола. Обычно это называют ping-pong. К примеру, в Jabber прям так и сделано.

Собственно в сокетах можно ещё поиграть Keep-Alive, но там иногда не все так очевидно https://rsdn.org/article/net/keep_alive.xml

Answer (score 2):

Стандартная ситуация описана, у примеру, [в мануале мелкомягких](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/disconnecting-the-client). Но это описано - как быть должно. Но на практике не всегда так бывает. Многие файрволы вообще не отвечают в ряде случаев, а просто "дропают" пакеты (одна из методик противодействия DDOS-атакам). Поэтому самый надежный случай, ИМХО, это - дожидаться факта закрытия коннекта за определенный промежуток времени. Если промежуток времени прошел, и никаких ответов не было - смело считать, что коннект уже сброшен.